# How do I preserve grid lines while specifying x-ticks and y-ticks?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I've drawn the following plot:

```latex
\begin{figure}[htpb]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
                domain=-3:5,
                smooth,
                axis x line=middle,
                axis y line=middle,
                xlabel=\(x\),
                ylabel=\(y\),
                grid=both,
                xtick={-1, 1},
                ytick={2, 3},
                ymin=-5,
                ymax=4,
            ]
            \addplot[black, thick] {-x^2 + 2 * x + 2};
            \addplot[red, thick, dashed] coordinates{(1,10) (1,-25)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
```

with the result being:
[image: graph with some grid lines missing]

How do I preserve the major/minor grid-lines while still specifying the ticks I want?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE :) I assume the screenshot you posted is not really the result of your code, is it?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to remove the default ticks with `xticklabels={}` and add your own with `extra x ticks={-1,0.5,1}` (for the y-axis accordingly). Usually, extra ticks bring their own grid lines. To disable this, you can use `extra tick style={grid=none}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
        domain=-3:5,
        smooth,
        axis x line=middle,
        axis y line=middle,
        xlabel=\(x\),
        ylabel=\(y\),
        grid=both,
        minor tick num=1,
        minor grid style={blue!10!white},
        extra tick style={grid=none},
        xticklabels={},
        extra x ticks={-1,0.5,1},
        yticklabels={},
        extra y ticks={2, 3},
        ymin=-5,
        ymax=4,
    ]
    \addplot[black, thick] {-x^2 + 2 * x + 2};
    \addplot[red, thick, dashed] coordinates{(1,10) (1,-25)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```